# Is there a way to programatically enable the Microsoft Scripting Runtime when opening a PPT Presentation?

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I have a PPT using VBA and it requires the Microsoft Scripting Runtime be enabled.  I have some customers that are not tech savvy and may not be able to follow the instructions I placed on a banner in the opening slide to enable it.  Is there a way to do it programatically when the presentation opens so they don't have to mess with it?

Comment: Do you mean enabled, or installed?  What is the exact problem your users are having?

Comment: @TimWilliams I mean enabled.  PPT maintains a reference to the scripting engine, but unless someone has enabled it or used .pptm files with VBA macros, it isn't enabled by default.  To prevent my users from opening the developer ribbon and the VBA editor to go to tools//references// and enable it, I would like to do it programatically when they open the PPT.

Comment: If that's the case then maybe you should switch your code to use late binding: eg see http://word.mvps.org/faqs/interdev/earlyvslatebinding.htm

Answer (score -2):

I hope the following link helps you:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/cristib/archive/2012/02/29/vba-programmatically-enable-access-to-the-vba-object-model-using-macros.aspx